# append formData multiple files and other inputs - php processing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have multiple forms generated dynamically.
I need to build the formData for multiple files as well as a couple of extra hidden inputs.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,

        beforeSend: function(){
        ...
        },
        success: function(){
        ...
        }
    });
});
```

Oddly enough, this works somehow, and the files do get uploaded to the server, I can perform all sorts of operations on the temp files but...
the files are never a part of the $_POST array if I var_dump $_POST the files are not in there.

Is there a better way to build the formData? am I missing something on the php side when I'm testing for isset($_POST['file[]'])

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Comment: It's there trust me. Otherwise, it would only upload the first image. The thing works but I can't figure out how the files are posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use php's files array.  print_r($_FILES); 
Doing the above print,  you'll be able to access every file sent from your form. This includes keys, tmp_name etc

Comment: never mind... I'm an idiot. the files do get posted fine. The problem is I was testing with isset($_POST['file[]']), which was always set but also empty if no files were actually uploaded. sigh

Comment: the other issue I was having was that I was not resetting the file field after each upload so the previous file(s) kept getting uploaded and messing up my testing. all works great now. thx everyone for trying to help